# LoadError when write sinatra helpers using bundler

Tags: sinatra, bundler, helper, modular

follow Sinatra write extension document, I write a `./lib/sinatra/test_helper.rb` file containing my TestHelper, but using `rackup` start I got this error:

```
/...PATH.../vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/backports-3.1.1/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra/testhelper (LoadError)
```

Seems Bundler could find my custom helpers extension. How to declare it in my Gemfile?

Comment: Have you written this module as a gem library or within an Sinatra project?

Comment: it's within a Sinatra project

Comment: Can you show us how your project is laid out please?

Comment: You probably are trying to use `less` and have not installed `therubyracer`. The `Less` compiler is a Javascript app.